# Is there an Ubuntu Solitaire that works like the Windows 7 game?

Tags: windows, windows-7, games

My aunt needs a new laptop and I'm planning to buy one for her and set it up with Xubuntu. She has been using Windows 7 so far, mostly for internet and office work. However, she has developed a certain... *addiction* to the stock Windows 7 Solitaire game.

When I set up her new computer, I want to install a Solitaire game for her that is as similar as possible to the Windows 7 game. Unfortunately I have never played Solitaire before and do not even have a computer at hand to compare the games.

Does someone have an idea of which game I could install for her out of the Ubuntu Software Center? (I don't want to add potentially unsafe PPAs) It should just be really simple and not have too many options and game modes, because that might even confuse her.

Thank you in advance and kind regards!

Comment: Set up wine and run the stock Win7 game

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `Aisleriot`. It works pretty much the same as Microsoft Solitaire and  is available in Ubuntu Software Center.

[image: Install via the software center]

You can install it via command line too :

```
sudo apt-get install aisleriot
```

[image: aisleriot]

Comment: Don't forget, if you do this, to make sure Aisleriot is doing the right solitaire game. It supports a great many different games, each with their own spreads and rules,and at one point at least, the default was *not* Klondike, which is what the Windows game is.

Comment: As far as I know, Aisleriot should be preinstalled on a default fresh Ubuntu installation. Not sure about Xubuntu though...

Comment: This is not the same.  You can't use the right-click shortcuts like in Windows.

Comment: You can also run Aisleriot via the command line: $ /usr/games/sol

Answer (score 4):

Another one is `ace-of-penguins`. You can install it  by typing

```
sudo apt-get install ace-of-penguins
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As @hg8 suggested `Aisleriot` is good.

You can also install `kpat`.

Open terminal and run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install kpat
```

Comment: Is this app only available for KDE desktop (i.e. Kubuntu), or does it run on e.g. Unity and XFCE as well?

Comment: @ByteCommander It will run on any desktop with the required Qt libraries installed (and a few KDE-runtime libraries)